# DNS IP Check Cpanel Reminder/Notice

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm

everyday i get following email from the cpanel, i dont know what it means and in current configuration, i have a one ip for a ns1.nameserver and one for ns2.nameserver but top level domain nameserver is mapped to one ip address. but there is no way to add a another A record to there (i dont knw how) or i want to disable this notice out, since still all works fine in the network...

```
The hostname (nameserver.com) resolves to 67.xxx. It should
resolve to 67.xxxx. Please be sure that the contents of
/etc/hosts are configured correctly, and also that there is a
correct 'A' entry for the domain in the zone file.

Some or all of these problems can be caused by /etc/resolv.conf
being setup incorrectly. Please check that file if you believe
everything else is correct.

You may be able to automatically correct this problem by using the
'Add an A entry for your hostname' option under 'Dns Functions' in
your Web Host Manager.
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to resolve the issue.

1. Add the correct A record for the IP and Fully Qualified Domain name
2. Per cPanel it is not suppose to function behind a NAT though as many have found this does in fact work. So you can "Fix" or stop this message by going into the contact manager and disable the “Ip address dns check” option

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have properly added A record for your hostname and assigned it to IP address of your server. For example, if your server hostname is xyz.abcd.com then you need to add xyz A record in abcd.com DNS zone and point it to your server IP address.